# Is $\frac{S_n-nE(X_1)}{\sqrt{n Var(X_1)}}$ a standardized random variable?

Tags: random, central-limit-theorem

I want to know if this statement is true or false.

The random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ fulfil the requirements of the central limit theorem. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Then

$$\frac{S_n-nE(X_1)}{\sqrt{n Var(X_1)}}$$

is a standardised random variable.

I looked up the central limit theorem, and the expected value has to be $0$ and the variance needs to be $1$ for this to be true. I think the expected value here is in fact $0$, but I don't know whether the variance is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expectation: $E[S_n-nE(X_1)]=E[S_n]-nE[X_1]=nE[X_1]-nE[X_1]=0$.

For the variance: $Var(\frac{S_n-nE(X_1)}{\sqrt{n Var(X_1)}})=\frac{1}{n Var(X_1)}Var(S_n-nE(X_1))=\frac{1}{n Var(X_1)}Var(S_n)=1$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know if convergence of a series of random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ in probability, or almost surely convergence of this series  both imply, that $X_n$ is approximately distributed for $n$ big?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand the question. Are you asking if convergence (in probability or a.s.) of $S_n$ implies convergence in distribution of $X_n$ to the normal distribution? Note that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. Also maybe have a look at Lindeberg-Feller, which states that a standardized independent array (like the one in your question) is standard normally distributed iff it satisfies the Lindeberg property.

Comment: Sorry, I should have maybe made another thread. The question wasn't related to the $S_n$ above

Comment: Does convergence of a series of random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ imply that $X_n$ is approximately normally distributed for $n$ big?

Comment: I don't think that's generally the case, without knowing what the sum of random variables converges to

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!!